# Return multiple outputs from a function in python

Tags: python, function

I would like to return multiple outputs when I call my function.
However, I do not want to return all outputs but only, say, the first, the third and the fourth from a total number of, say, 7 outputs.

I've tried s.th. like this but this leads to an error:

```
a, b, c = myfunc()[[0, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: `a,_, b,c,*_= myfunc()`

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack the return value :

```
a,_, b,c,*_= myfunc()
```